# Firebase assistants error: Failed to resolve: firebase-messaging-15.0.0

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently facing the error when i try to connect to the Cloud Messaging using firebase assistants.

> Failed to resolve: firebase-messaging-15.0.0

I search online, and the solution was to remove the last few digits in the dependency. However, when i tried that, it solved the error, but on the firebase assistants, it did not show "dependency being set up correctly" anymore. Hence, does this mean that i am not connected to the firebase cloud messaging?

Method tried:
change from  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0:15.0.0' to  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'

[The dependency being set up correctly is in green before i use the online method of removing the last few digits of the dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYCSU.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> Failed to resolve: firebase-messaging-15.0.0

Because you are using a wrong dependency in your code. To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0:15.0.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
```

Because such a version `17.0.0:15.0.0` does not exist. [Here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) you can find more informations.

In your top level `build.gradle` file please be sure to have the latest version of Google Service plugin and Gradle:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply it fixed the error, but somehow my device still doesn't receive the notification that is sent from firebase console

Comment: If you say that it fixed the error, it means that the initial problem is solved and this are good news :) The fact that you don't receive notification sounds as a new issue which basically should be considered another question that cannot be answered in a comment or using only the data above. As a personal guess, I think that i something related to the depencencies but in order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question using a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other users can help you.

Answer (score 2):

remove all firebase-messaging dependency and add This Dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
```