# Firebase Failed to resolve: firebase-messaging-15.0.0 (Previous solutions disconnect Firebase Connection)

Tags: firebase

I have been trying to set up Firebase Cloud Messaging on an app. Everything runs ok until I add FCM dependencies to the app. I immediately get this error:

> Failed to resolve: firebase-messaging-15.0.0
>   Open File

Here are the dependencies;

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0:15.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have been reading answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53219484/firebase-assistants-error-failed-to-resolve-firebase-messaging-15-0-0) all day and the only solution that works involves deleting everything from ": - 0" in the last line of the code.

The problem is that it immediately removes the connection to FCM. New to android programming, so forgive any obvious oversight. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the version of the dependencies conflict. You can remove one of the version and select the preferred one. In this case your

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0:15.0.0'`

seems to have double version. You should choose whether to use 17.0.0 or 15.0.0 one.
The detail can be found in this video 
https://youtu.be/NN_Ch5qzFWQ

cheers !